# laravel install getting key generate error in ubunto OS

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, installation

I am install "Laravel Framework version 5.2.26" but i am getting error for key generate in my ubuntu os

```
user@CN43:/var/www/html/laravel_1$ php artisan key:generate

  [ErrorException]                                                             
  file_get_contents(/var/www/html/laravel_1/.env): failed to open stream: No   
  such file or directory
```

So i have check that directory .env file is not there but .env.example file only there so i created that file and update database name, database username, database password after that "php artisan key:generate" command is worked that key was generated above 32 characters and its get [base64:somethingsstrings with above 32 characters] i think some installation issues is there.

my laravel site is not opening. what i do mistake?

Answer (score 13):

Rename `.env.example` to `.env` and fill all properties.

> If you install Laravel via Composer, this file will automatically be
>   renamed to .env. Otherwise, you should rename the file manually

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: yes already i will do it but key is generate with base64 and also that key is not working

Comment: Application key [base64:uD6hjLx+j1uMYDBEi7GMz8eMgD/KHc8W27rwSko8Cos=] set successfully. if renamed this way of key is generate but that key is not working

Comment: Check your `.env` file, it should have line like this: `APP_KEY=6u6l2E7WlmrV4jvE2eciHM9dkRCQz20F`

Comment: So, problem with key generation solved. If your app still not working, you should post another question and describe a problem and post full error message.

Comment: @BalaguruMurugan, please upvote and choose this answer as best answer if you want to thank me for my time.

Comment: I find that renaming this file inside "Visual Studio Code" is better.. Hard to explain why..

Answer (score 8):

Run this command and make .env file from .env.example file:

```
cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate
```

Now it's generate the key. Don't create new .env file.