# Laravel Framework version 5.2.26 install getting key generate error in ubuntu os

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, installation

I am install "Laravel Framework version 5.2.26" but i am getting error for key generate in my ubuntu os

```
user@CN43:/var/www/html/laravel_1$ php artisan key:generate

  [ErrorException]                                                             
  file_get_contents(/var/www/html/laravel_1/.env): failed to open stream: No   
  such file or directory
```

After that i will update `.env.example` file to `.env` and update all information in `.env` file after key generate command return that key is

```
user@CN43:/var/www/html/laravel_1$ php artisan key:generate
Application key [base64:uD6hjLx+j1uMYDBEi7GMz8eMgD/KHc8W27rwSko8Cos=] set successfully.
```

but that key is not working. what is wrong???

In my console error in chrome is

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
http://localhost/laravel_1/public/:1 GET http://localhost/laravel_1/public/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
http://localhost/laravel_1/public/:1 GET http://localhost/laravel_1/public/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

`.env` file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:i7WQo9iUSQud+Oi90HGJzonE4w+SPaV3NI3AMBnee3A=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_master
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: pls show your .env file

Comment: Why do you think a problem is in a key here? Please show what code generates this errors (controller or code in `routes.php`).

Comment: i update questio with env file

Comment: @BalaguruMurugan so your .env is now fine, `php artisan key:generate` should now running fine, so the problem is not with your APP_KEY, now you need to show your controller file and exception if any appear on your screen

Comment: please check that your APP_KEY is more that 32 characters.It will be 32 characters not more or less

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276767/laravel-install-getting-key-generate-error-in-ubunto-os

more than 32 characters and above url also post that question in myself

Answer (score 0):

If you have just run "php artisan vendor:publish" like I did. Then most likely your artisan has been updated but not your larafel/framework. 
Run `"composer update"` and then rerun `"php artisan key:generate"` you will see the difference in your .env file, copy the key and put it in config/app.php in this format:

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'base64:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=')
```

Now your app should back and running properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you have to change the .env by doing this
           `cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate`

ref: [laravel install getting key generate error in ubunto OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276767/laravel-install-getting-key-generate-error-in-ubunto-os/36279613)

Answer (score 0):

Run     **cp .env.example .env**
    then    **php artisan key:generate**
Copy the displayed key something like, "base64:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx="

Then go to yourAppName\config\app.php then paste the copied key in it(around line 107) then Save.

Run **php artisan serve**

Answer (score -2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvtsX.png)

You can copy the .env.example to .env 
in your laravel root folder