# No Application Encryption Key Has Been Specified

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to use the `Artisan` command like this:

```
php artisan serve
```

It displays:

> Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000

However, it won't automatically launch and when I manually enter http://127.0.0.1:8000 it shows this error:

> RuntimeException No application encryption key has been specified.

What's the cause of this problem, and how can it be fixed?

I'm using **Laravel framework 5.5-dev**.

Comment: or if your .env file needs to be changed ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276767/laravel-install-getting-key-generate-error-in-ubunto-os/36279613

Comment: The answers below are correct: however, if you first run "php artisan serve" and have an active web server session you will need to restart the server (control-c in the terminal to stop) to get the change to take effect after you add the key to your .env file.

Answer (score 692, accepted):

From [Encryption - Laravel - The PHP Framework For Web Artisans](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/encryption#configuration):

> "Before using Laravel's encrypter, you must set a key option in your
> config/app.php configuration file. You should use the
> `php artisan key:generate` command to generate this key"

From Encryption - Laravel - The PHP Framework For Web Artisans:

```
"Before using Laravel's encrypter, you must set a key option in your config/app.php configuration file. You should use the php artisan key:generate command to generate this key"
```

I found it using this query in google.com:
`"laravel add encrption key"` (Yes, it worked even with the typo!)

Note that if the .env file contains the key but you are still getting an application key error, then run `php artisan config:cache` to clear and reset the config.

Comment: Im sorry so are you putting php artisan key:generate in the terminal? because I get an ErrorException

Comment: For anyone else that ran into my issue  input this into the terminal              cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate

Comment: `php artisan key:generate` does not even work for me. Gives me the same error **No application encryption key has been specified**, please any solution?

Comment: This worked for me, but I first had to rename the file .env.example to .env for this to work, otherwise I was getting ".env: no such file" error.

Comment: Works, but first you need to create an empty .env file, and then copy the contents of .env.example, to your .env file. The .env.exampe file has an 'APP_KEY=' line, where 'APP_KEY' is the key, and nothing is specified as the value. If you don't have the the 'APP_KEY=' line, it seems it will not add the generated key to the .env file. I also then had to run 'php artisan config:cache' and then restart the server, for it to work.

Comment: Don't forget 'php artisan config:cache' after you generate your key. You need this especially after moving from another server, or whenever making changes to config or the .env on a working app

Comment: If you are using `php artisan serve` you need to restart the server after changing the `.env` file.

Answer (score 228):

In my case, I also needed to reset the cached config files:

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: What is `php artisan config:cache` for? Why is it useful?

Comment: @Pathros to create/regenerate the cached config files

Comment: In addition to this, first, ensure that your "`.env`" file at least contains the empty key-option, like: `APP_KEY=`

Comment: Or, for local development use `php artisan config:clear`, and it won't generate a new cached version.

Comment: `php artisan config:cache` is what I missed. I've typed it in and the very same moment this page loaded :)

Comment: If Laravel has cached a configuration value, updating the `.env` file won't have an immediate effect. You need to refresh the configuration cache using `php artisan config:cache` or clear the old cache with `php artisan config:clear` for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 66):

Open command prompt in the root folder of your project and run below command:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

It will generate Application Key for your application.

You can find the generated application key(APP_KEY) in `.env` file.

Answer (score 34):

1. Copy `.env.example` to `.env`:

   `cp -a .env.example .env`
2. Generate a key:

   `php artisan key:generate`
3. Only then run:

   `php artisan serve`

Comment: Whoops. This was the critical step! A fresh Laravel project needs a .env file or nothing will work. Thanks, Adam.

Answer (score 26):

Simply run this command:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: Yes but many hosting server do not have command line access then how to do?

Comment: a majority support ssh connection. from your terminal  run ssh yourusername@server_ip

Answer (score 19):

`cp .env.example .env` if there is no .env file present.
`php artisan key:generate` command works for me. It generates the encryption key

Comment: clear the cache using `php artisan config:cache` command after the above steps.

Comment: Cache clearing would mostly be required of the production / staging but not during development. (Unless you like to cache your views during development).

Answer (score 15):

Open command prompt in the root folder of your project and run

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Then

```
php artisan config:cache
```

and Then

If you're getting the same error after having key-value, then just copy the APP_KEY value from .env file and paste it to config/app.php with 'key' => 'YOUR KEY',

and then again run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 13):

I actually had to add a *.env* file to my project and then copy the contents of *.env.example* so that the `key:generate` would work. Not sure why a *.env* file was not created when I started the project.

Comment: It might depend on how you installed Laravel ... "_In a fresh Laravel installation, the root directory of your application will contain a `.env.example` file. If you install Laravel via Composer, this file will automatically be renamed to `.env`. Otherwise, you should rename the file manually._" -[#Environment Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#environment-configuration)

Comment: also, if you cloned the project from a repo where the .env file was likely in .gitignore, then you would neeed to create it as well. From the Laravel docs: 'Your .env file should not be committed to your application's source control, since each developer / server using your application could require a different environment configuration'

Comment: I also found that if you download it from the cloud (I'm using windows) i.e. google-drive, sky-drive etc. the .env, .env.example files are named _env, _env.example etc.
In that case I renamed the files accordingly and then just ran 'php artisan key:generate'.

Answer (score 13):

In 3 steps:

Generate new key `php artisan key:generate`

Clear the config `php artisan config:clear`

Update cache `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 11):

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache
```

worked for me, but it had to be done in a command prompt on Windows.

Doing it inside the terminal in PHPStorm didn't worked.

Answer (score 10):

A common issue you might experience when working on a Laravel application is the exception:

> RuntimeException No application encryption key has been specified.

You'll often run into this when you pull down an existing Laravel application, where you copy the `.env.example` file to `.env` but don't set a value for the `APP_KEY` variable.

At the command line, issue the following Artisan command to generate a key:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

This will generate a random key for `APP_KEY`, After completion of `.env` edit please enter this command in your terminal for clear cache:`php artisan config:cache`

Also, If you are using the PHP's default web server (eg. `php artisan serve`) you need to **restart the server** changing your `.env` file values. now you will not get to see this error message.

Answer (score 8):

Simply run command **php artisan key:generate**.. Still issue exist then run one more command **php artisan config:cache** and **php artisan cache:clear** ..

Now run **php artisan serve**

Answer (score 7):

Follow this steps:

1. `php artisan key:generate`
2. `php artisan config:cache`
3. `php artisan serve`

Comment: even after generating key in .env file i was getting error. When i ran "php artisaan config:cache" it cleared cache and then only my problem solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Remember to point to the database and close the .env file. If the .env file is open the error will continue.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I'll write another instruction, because didn't find the clear answer here. So if you faced such problems, follow this:

1. Rename or copy/rename **.env.example** file in the root of your project to **.env**.

> You should not just create empty **.env** file, but fill it with
>   content of **.env.example**.

2. In the terminal go to the project root directory(not public folder) and run

> php artisan key:generate

3. If everything is okay, the response in the terminal should look like this

> Application key [base64:wbvPP9pBOwifnwu84BeKAVzmwM4TLvcVFowLcPAi6nA=]
>   set successfully.

4. Now just copy key itself and paste it in your **.env** file as the value to APP_KEY. Result line should look like this:

> APP_KEY=base64:wbvPP9pBOwifnwu84BeKAVzmwM4TLvcVFowLcPAi6nA=

5. In terminal run

> php artisan config:cache

That's it.

Comment: So `php artisan key:generate` didn't automatically add the key to your .env file?

Comment: No, in my case.

Answer (score 5):

I found that most answers are incomplete here. In case anyone else is still looking for this:

1. Check if you have **APP_KEY=** in your .env, if not just add it without a value.
2. Run this command: **php artisan key:generate**. This will fill in the value to the APP_KEY in your .env file.
3. Finally, run **php artisan config:cache** in order to clear your config cache and recache your config with the new APP_KEY value.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate Application Encryption Key using this command:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Then, create a cache file for faster configuration loading using this command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Or, serve the application on the PHP development server using this command:

```
php artisan serve
```

That's it!

Answer (score 3):

If you git clone some project then this kind of issue may usually occur.

1. make sure there is `.env` file
2. run `php artisan key:generate` and then it should generate **APP_KEY** in .env
3. finally run `php artisan serve` and it should be working.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a `.env` file then run the below command, else skip this

```
cp .env.example .env
```

Then run the below artisan command and it will generate an application key for your project:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

**Note:** Your `APP_KEY` is inside your `.env` file.

Answer (score 3):

If after running `php artisan key:generate` issue is not resolved, check your `.env` file.

Search for `APP_KEY=`.

If it doesn't exist, manually add it to `.env` file and run `php artisan key:generate` again.

After this you will see generated key in `.env` file.

Copy that key and paste it in `/config/app.php` (search for `APP_KEY` there as well). You should end up with something like this in `app.php` file

`'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'base64:...'),`

Then run `php artisan serve` (You might have to run `php artisan config:cache` at some point. Not 100% sure when)

Answer (score 2):

Facing the Same Issue in Laravel v8.49.0 (PHP v8.0.6)                                                                      Solution
[image: genrate app key]

1. Click

> Genrate app key

[image: succesfully genrate key]

2. Click on Refresh now

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when I manually copied the contents of my Laravel project (say sites/oldname) into a new directory on my Mac (say, sites/newname).  Since I was manually dragging and droppping, it didn't grab the hidden files, namely, '.env'.
When I looked more closely at sites/oldname I saw .editorconfig, .env, .env.example, .gitatrributes, .styleci.yml, etc.

The error went away once I copied the hidden files to the new directory.

So, "No Application Encryption Key Has Been Specified" is Laravel speak for "your .env file is missing."

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes If everything Fails Use this:

Goto: `laravelProject/config/app.php`

Find the line: `'key' =>` and check to what it refers,

It can either be one of two:

Case 1: `env('APP_KEY')`
Case 2: `"somekeystring"`

For Case 1:
Goto your .env file after you have run  `cp -a .env.example .env`
Enter a random string like `10101010101010101010101010101010`

Now, run `php artisan key:generate`

Your key will be updated automatically.

For Case 2:
set a random string like  for value of Key `10101010101010101010101010101010`

Now, run `php artisan key:generate`

Your key will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Run below command to set `app key`

```
php artisan key:generate
```

By running the above command, it sets the key value in `.env` of your project directory which is referenced in the app config

```
// .env
APP_KEY=base64:XkrFWC+TGnySY2LsldPXAxuHpyjh8UuoPMt6yy2gJ8U=


// config/app.php
'key' => env(APP_KEY);
```

Restart your server, in order to reflect the above change.

Answer (score 1):

Among many other reasons which I have faced during my years of working with Laravel, most of them are already mentioned here in answers, one strange thing I got this issue in in server was because I forgot to run the command:

`php artisan storage:link`

Hope this helps someone else, but try it after using other solutions as they address the most common causes.

Answer (score 0):

**simply run**

```
php artisan key:generate
```

*its worked for me*

Answer (score 0):

Try setting correct file permissions

```
chmod -R 777 storage/
chmod 777 bootstrap/cache/
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to restart my queue worker using `php artisan queue:restart` after running `php artisan key:generate` to get jobs working.