# Laravel 5.7 email verify broken link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I followed Laravels docs ([link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification)) about Email verification. Everything seems to work except for a `403 - invalid signature`. This errors shows when clicking on the email link. I'm using shared hosting.

**Url is similar to this:**

> [..]email/verify/21?expires=154270[..]&signature=920dcb9ac2fbf5[..]

would appreciate all the help I could get! Thanks!

Comment: More detail please.

Comment: Did you added the `Auth::routes(['verify'=>true]);`

Comment: Yes, all steps in docs is done. @OmarAbdullah

Comment: Also set the `APP_URL` in `.env` and do  `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: That's also done @OmarAbdullah

Comment: Is it on local or staging/Production ?

Comment: Shared hosting but not "production" @OmarAbdullah

Comment: Does you `APP_URL` contains `https://` ?

Comment: Yes, APP_URL=https://[..]. Where is the token saved? Could it be the problem? @OmarAbdullah

Comment: checkout these fixes :https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/hitting-403-page-when-clicking-verify-link-in-email-using-new-laravel-verification-57

Comment: Tried changing TrustProxies middleware but same problem. (Not using heroku) @OmarAbdullah

Comment: What could it be? Please help  @OmarAbdullah

Comment: try changing to https: or change the APP_ENV to local or production and clear config. Or manually remove the https; and change it to https in the link

Comment: What do you mean with, manually remove https? No affects so far. Created email_verified_at column manually, its a timestamp set to null, right? @OmarAbdullah

Comment: Maybe @JesusErwinSuarez could help?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44839664

You have to generate a key: `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: **Never ever** do that. This first step is made as soon as the app is created and if you run it again no one would be able to login or your encrypted images would be encrypted **forever**.

Comment: In my case it was so that I wanted to deliver my software and there was no key on the server. You're right, it's not a good idea to do that with the environment up and running.