# i must press enter on running tests using phpunit in laravel

Tags: laravel, windows-10, phpunit, mockery

i must press enter on running tests using phpunit in Laravel 5.7.

On every test i get following Message:

> 1) Tests\Feature\DepartmentsTest::a_admin_can_create_a_department
>   Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Received
>   Mockery_1_Illuminate_Console_OutputStyle::askQuestion(), but no
>   expectations were specified

by setting following to false, the error disappear:

```
public $mockConsoleOutput = false;
```

After that the window hangs on running the test suite and i need to press enter to run the tests.

How can i fix that?

I´am using Windows 10 + PHPUnit 7.5.1 and Laravel 5.7.19

Thanks in advance!

```
/** @test */
public function a_admin_can_create_a_department()
    {

        // $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $attributes = [
            'description' => 'Service',
            'accessible_by_depart' => true
        ];

        $this->post('/tools/api/storeDepartment', $attributes);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('departments', $attributes);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the `Tests\Feature\DepartmentsTest::a_admin_can_create_a_department ` code?

Comment: @Peter edited the post, see above

Comment: Can you show your `$this->post()` method too? Basically we need to see where you are setting up your mock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now I finally found the solution.

On my migration from Laravel 5.1 to Laravel 5.2 (a long time ago) i forgot to add the following lines to the config/app.php File:

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services the application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */
    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
```

Now everything works fine.

Greetings Daniel

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the problem for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48303288/2171254

After doing that, I didn't need the line `public $mockConsoleOutput = false;`

Greetings