# Getting 500 server error with Laravel 5.7 on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, http-status-code-500

I have cloned repo from git, and made `composer install`.

Then I am starting a server, but every time I get **500 server error**.

Also, I tried to create a new project with `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`
and this project works fine.

In my error log i got an error like:

> production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified.
>   {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application
>   encryption key has been specified. at
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\contact-fw-domanskyi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:44)
>   [stacktrace]

Comment: Please share what you have in your log to get a better help, just 500 doesn't says a lot. You can check the error log within your project `storage/logs` directory.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons for this. But unless you give us more information there is little we can do but ___play 20 questions___

Comment: There are many same errors: 
production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at C:\\OSPanel\\domains\\contact-fw-domanskyi\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:44)
[stacktrace]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Application Encryption Key Has Been Specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839648/no-application-encryption-key-has-been-specified)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer based on your comment under in your question:

> RuntimeException No application encryption key has been specified.

set a value for the `APP_KEY` variable.

At the command line, the following Artisan command to generate a key:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

This will generate a random key, you must **restart the server** and you should no longer see the error message.

Comment: My problem was .env was missing. I was doing this in the terminal. `cp .env.example .env` To make a fresh .env and then I ran the artisan command `php artisan key:generate`

Answer (score 18):

When you clone the git repo you must follow these steps to run the project:

1. Create a Database locally
2. Rename **.env.example** file to **.env** inside your project root and fill the 
   database information. (windows won't let you do it, so you have to open your console 
   cd your project root directory and run **mv .env.example .env** )
3. Open the console and cd your project root directory
4. Run `composer install`
5. Run `php artisan key:generate`
6. Run `php artisan migrate`
7. Run `php artisan db:seed` to run seeders, if any.
8. Run `php artisan serve`

Now, your project will run. Good Luck!!

Answer (score 2):

I just missed **.env** file.

I have created new and generated a new key using `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: Yes. My problem was also .env was missing. I was doing this in the terminal. `cp .env.example .env` To make a fresh .env and then I ran the artisan command `php artisan key:generate`