# No application encryption key has been specified (react)

Tags: reactjs, laravel

my api work in PostMan but not in react and show this error

> No application encryption key has been specified

```
fetch(URL, {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Language': 'en',      },
  body: formUrlEncoded(data),
})
```

Comment: use this command in your console ` php artisan key:generate ` this will generate the application key and then you can use it.

Comment: how the key in header of request ?

Comment: It'll be set automatically. Try the command and you'll see the required result

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan serve
```

or

```
php artisan key:generate --env=testing
```

Comment: This subject may interest you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839648/no-application-encryption-key-has-been-specified?rq=1