# CICD code deploy success in AWS after tests fails at git action Laravel

Tags: laravel, github-actions, cicd, aws-code-deploy, aws-pipeline

this is my yml file below. However code still deploying success on AWS even if my unit test fails on git actions. Please help! I don't understand what triggering the deployment. What should I do?

[image: test fails]

This is the deploy.yml inside git->workflow

```yaml
name: CI/CD Pipeline
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  continuous-integration:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Install PHP and dependencies
      run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install php php-mbstring php-xml

    - name: Install Composer dependencies
      run: composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.SSH_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-1
      
    - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
        DB_DATABASE: database/database.sqlite
      run: vendor/bin/phpunit

  continuous-deployment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [continuous-integration]
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    steps:
     # Step 1
    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.SSH_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-1
     # Step 2
    - name: Create CodeDeploy Deployment
      id: deploy
      run: |
        aws deploy create-deployment \
          --application-name application-name \
          --deployment-group-name AppDeploymentGroupName \
          --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime \
          --github-location repository=${{ github.repository }},commitId=${{ github.sha }}
```

This is `appspec.yml`:

```yaml
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/test.jitume
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: ./scripts/after-install.sh
      runas: ubuntu

#BeforeInstall
#AfterInstall
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Application Encryption Key Has Been Specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839648/no-application-encryption-key-has-been-specified)