# How to solve php artisan key generate error?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.5

I created a new Laravel 5.5 project with this command:

> laravel new crud-angular

After then, run this command inside the project folder:

> php artisan key:generate

At that moment, I got such error:

> Warning: require(F:\Study\Laravel\crud-angular/vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   F:\Study\Laravel\crud-angular\artisan on line 18
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'F:\Study\Laravel\crud-angular/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   F:\Study\Laravel\crud-angular\artisan on line 18

I used wampserver 3.0.6 for this project.
Hope to help me.
Thanks

Comment: can you do a `composer update` ?

Comment: I already did it. But I had the same error. :(

Comment: try to give permisson  vendor folder

Comment: Ensure you create .env from .env.example.

 reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/36276801/9808588

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you have run:

```
composer install
```

Now it seems packages are not installed. If they are, try running:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved the problem. Highly recommend you. Keep in touch. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to to give permission for that vendor folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 vendor
```

**update your composer also**

```
composer update
```

this will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot to Install composer just run `composer install`